# ASP.NET project reference not found...at all?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image: Screenshot]

Above are the problems I am having right now, and I can't contact the old programmer. The AjaxToolkit is referencing to him and I have no idea where to change that reference. Or where to get that exact part of the Toolkit that it's looking for.

TL;DR:

- Check the link.
- Where do I change this reference?
- Where do I find AjaxControlToolkit-Framework3.5SP1\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs?

Comment: have you checked the references folder in the project?  if there is a reference to the ajaxcontroltoolkit and it seems to be broken now, you could try to download it again and reference the new one to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the path of your references in the .csproj file

PS : To open up your csproj Right click on your project from your IDE > Open Folder In Windows explorer > You can find a file with csproj extension > Edit with notepad

Comment: There was actually nothing in that file with that reference. Only stuff like: 

Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\Desktop\Program för jobb\www.website.com\"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\www.website.com\"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"

Comment: I just created a new project, I added a new reference "AjaxControlToolkit.dll" to that project , I built that project and I checked the csproj file , a new line has been added:
<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit><HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET35\fr\AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

Comment: There are two ways to change path of your reference in the csproj ,
either by changing references one by one just like the example above or by changing the path of all your references in the property group:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <ReferencePath>c:\bla\bla\bla\</ReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>